# How to center a form element (search box) inside of Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the search box to be in the center of my Bootstrap navbar. Removing navbar-left seems to destroy the alignment on the navbar. Im going for something like the [linkedin.com](http://linkedin.com) page. Whats the easiest way to do this?
Heres a link to a JSFiddle of my navbar https://jsfiddle.net/b6pmy9w4/. Thanks in advance for any help. 
 
Html Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border-radius: 0;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed burger-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand jura-font" href="/#!/">COLIGN</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> -->
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">View Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manage Account</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Invite a friend</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="/auth/signout">Log out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best way to do it but

- Remove the `navbar-left`
- Move it after the `ul`
- Set `text-align:center`

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/b6pmy9w4/1/)

Comment: It seems to work without setting display:block, do you think its ok if I don't include it?

Comment: @DanielJacobson yeah sorry that was stupid of me, forms have a display block by default no need for it.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old now, but on Bootstrap4 I just added the ml-auto class to the form tag and it worked perfectly:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto">
```

You can also add the col classes to change the size of the form input and the button.